# .CPP File and .EXE File With Inconsistant Logic

Tags: c++

I've never run into this issue before where when I build my code, the main error checking if statement runs correctly in the console.

```
ifstream inputfile;
inputfile.open("arrayNumbers.txt");

if(inputfile) //<----- This is working correctly in the CPP, but not in the EXE
{
```

Unfortunately when I go to run the executable file, that if statement kicks out to the "File not opened" else portion

```
else
{
    cout << "File did not open" << endl; 
            //^^^^In the exe, the program skips the rest of the code and kicks here
}
```

Anyone have any clue as to why this is happening?

Compiler is Visual Studio 2010

I have run it in both debug and release mode as well

Comment: I assume when you mean you "run the CPP" you're launching the program from Visual Studio's Debug menu, and when you run the EXE you're actually double click on the EXE file (or equivelant) - if that's the case, the problem probably lies with where the arrayNumbers.txt file is. Try copying that file to the folder with the EXE and running the EXE then

Comment: Correct about the Debug menu. I thought Visual Studio would read the entire program folder looking for the text file, but I guess not. Copied it over and it found it fine. Any reason why VS won't search all the folders?

Comment: Visual Studio doesn't search for the file: The program opens the file from what it considers its "current directory": when you run the EXE file directly this directory is where the EXE file is, when you run it from Visual Studio, Visual Studio sets the current directory to be something related to the project as a convenience for you. Note that in both cases you're actually running the same EXE file- Visual Studio must compile the C++ source into an EXE in order to run it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is likely to do with where the file `arrayNumbers.txt` is stored, move the file into the same folder with the executable and it should work.

Comment: I thought VS would search all the files for it but I guess not. Went ahead and moved it over and the executable ran fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When you run in Visual Studio the file is running from the Solution folder, when you double click the .exe you run from the Project->Debug-> folder most of the time

You can maybe add a Post Build Event to your project to automatically copy the file to your output dir.

```
copy $(SolutionDir)/arrayNumbers.txt $(OutDir)
```

Comment: Cool. Good to keep in mind for future projects. *The more you know*